# Devirtualizing a non-final method

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++14

Suppose I have a class setup like the following:

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual void foo() { printf("default implementation\n"); }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    void foo() override { printf("B implementation\n"); }
};

class  C : public B {
  public:
    inline void foo() final { A::foo(); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  auto c = new C();
  c->foo();
}
```

In general, can the call to `c->foo()` be devirtualized and inlined down to the `printf("default implementation")` call? Is this guaranteed, for example in gcc? My intuition is that `A::foo()` is non-virtual because the class is specified explicitly, and so the `printf` will always be inlined.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking about optimizations, so in general we have to pick a compiler and try it. We can look at the assembly output to determine if the compiler is optimizing the way you want.

#### [Let's try GCC 5.2:](https://goo.gl/nkSg8R)

```
.LC0:
    .string "B implementation"
B::foo():
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    jmp puts
.LC2:
    .string "default implementation"
A::foo():
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    jmp puts
C::foo():
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    jmp puts
main:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movl    $8, %edi
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    call    puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

#### [And let's try out Clang 3.6](https://goo.gl/HctSB1):

```
main:                                   # @main
    pushq   %rax
    movl    $.Lstr, %edi
    callq   puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rdx
    retq

.Lstr:
    .asciz  "default implementation"
```

In both cases you can see that pretty clearly that all of the virtual functions have been inlined.

#### "Is this guaranteed, for example in gcc?"

If the compiler is confident about what the actual type of an object is, then I suspect this optimization will always happen. I don't have anything to back up this claim though.