# in what way runtime polymorphism differs from compile time

Tags: c++, polymorphism, runtime, virtual, overriding

This is a traditional example of runtime polymorphism

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void show() { cout<<" In Base \n"; }
    void show(int x) { cout<<"over loaded method base";}
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void show() { cout<<"In Derived \n"; } 
    void show(int x) { cout<<"over loaded method derived";}
};

int main(void) {   
    Base *bp = new Derived;
    Base *bp2=new Base;
    bp2->show(10); //Case 1: COMPILE-TIME POLYMORPHISM (overloading)
    bp->show();  //Case 2: RUN-TIME POLYMORPHISM (overriding)
    return 0;
}
```

//Output : overloaded method base
//         in derived

why can compiler understand which method to call during compile time in case 1 and not in case 2.
in Case 2-As it is clear to the compiler that derived class obj is stored in bp and show is virtual so why cant it decide which show() to call at compile time itself.

Comment: There is no compile-time polymorphism (which is related to templates) in your example. You have regular polymorphism through virtual functions for `show()` and you are hiding a function from the base class in the derived class for `show(int)`.

Comment: It is clear in this example that `bp` points to a `Derived` object, but what if the pointer was a parameter? How far should the compiler look to see what type was really allocated? That would make C++ compilers even slower than they are already. So the rules allow it to be short-sighted in this case, when calling non-virtual functions.

Comment: @bku_drytt there is compile time poly.. as bp2 is used to call show(10). plz check code again.its not function hiding

Comment: @NeilKirk So is it like this. If compiler sees same type object stored in same type variable it decides in compile time and if some other type obj is stored in some other variable it postpones this decision to run time ???

Comment: If it's non-virtual, it calls the function based on the type of the pointer. If it's virtual, it calls the function based on the actual type of object.

Comment: There is no overloading in your example.

Comment: @NeilKirk okay your answer makes sense but if i write Base *bp= new Base; and call the virtual function with bp will till also be runtime polymorphism or no polymorphism??This is the last doubt i have

Comment: It is run-time polymorphism. However compilers are able to optimize out the run-time lookup and decide the function to call at compile-time if they can guarantee which function will be called. But the behavior of the code must still be as if it were handled as run-time polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

> why can compiler understand which method to call during compile time in case 1 and not in case 2

```
bp2->show(10);
```

resolves to `Base::show(int)` since it is not a `virtual` function.

```
bp->show(10);
```

will also resolve to `Base::show(int)` even though `bp` points to a `Derived` object.

If you want the call to be directed to `Derived::show(int)`, the function has to be called on a `Derived` object or a pointer.

```
Derived *dp = new Derived;
Base *bp = dp;

dp->show(10);   // Resolves to Derived::show(int)
bp->show(10);   // Resolves to Base::show(int)
```

As far as resolving which virtual member function to call at compile time, a compiler can do it in some cases. It depends on the compiler and level of optimization you use. It is, however, not guaranteed by the language.

A related question on resolving virtual member function calls at compile time: [Devirtualizing a non-final method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720642/devirtualizing-a-non-final-method)

Comment: Do you know what function overriding is? Also i am calling bp->show() not bp->show(10) both are different the first one is virtual

Comment: @SaurabhKumar, I am not talking about the virtual member function in my answer. I am trying to explain to you how the call to the non-virtual member is resolved.

Comment: yes but my question is abt why the virtual function call cant be resolved in compile time itself

Comment: @SaurabhKumar, it can in some cases. It depends on the compiler and level of optimization you use. It is, however, not guaranteed by the language.

Comment: Related to your question about virtual member functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720642/devirtualizing-a-non-final-method

Comment: @R Sahu Okay I understand now, based on you last comment and Neil's comment its states that when the function is virtual the compiler calls function based on type of object.thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solves my doubt NeilKirk's and R Sahu's comment-

```
If it's non-virtual, it calls the function based on the type of the pointer. If it's virtual, it calls the function based on the actual type of object.
```

which will be known as runtime